# jQuery toggling the class with .removeClass() and .addClass() not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have implemented toggling in my way as described code below.
**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="selectCol"><div class="unCheckedCheckBoxAll"></div></th>
            <th class="nosCol">Products</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="unCheckedCheckBox"></div></td>
        <td>ABCD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="unCheckedCheckBox"></div></td>
        <td>PQRS</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
.unCheckedCheckBox, .unCheckedCheckBoxAll
{
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   margin-top: -4px;
   background: transparent url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsaPu.png) top left no-repeat;
}
.CheckedCheckBox,.CheckedCheckBoxAll
{
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   margin-top: -4px;
   background: transparent url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsaPu.png) 0 -60px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".CheckedCheckBox").click(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('CheckedCheckBox').addClass('unCheckedCheckBox');
    if ($(".CheckedCheckBox").length == 0) {
        $('.CheckedCheckBoxAll').removeClass('CheckedCheckBoxAll').addClass('unCheckedCheckBoxAll');
    }
});
$(".unCheckedCheckBox").click(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('unCheckedCheckBox').addClass('CheckedCheckBox');
    if ($(".unCheckedCheckBox").length == 0) {
        $('.unCheckedCheckBoxAll').removeClass('unCheckedCheckBoxAll').addClass('CheckedCheckBoxAll');
    }
});
$(".CheckedCheckBoxAll").click(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('CheckedCheckBoxAll').addClass('unCheckedCheckBoxAll');
    $('.CheckedCheckBox').removeClass('CheckedCheckBox').addClass('unCheckedCheckBox');
});
$(".unCheckedCheckBoxAll").click(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('unCheckedCheckBoxAll').addClass('CheckedCheckBoxAll');
    $('.unCheckedCheckBox').removeClass('unCheckedCheckBox').addClass('CheckedCheckBox');
});
```

Now the problem is, when I click on unchecked div, it becomes checked div but when I click on checked div, it goes in unchecked function though class is checked.
Help me. I am not getting what's problem.

Here is the jsfiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/nscZA/3/

Image I am using:

[image]

Comment: You dont have jQuery loaded in your fiddle, select it on the left side.

Comment: Using a `div` element as button? Why?

Comment: @undefined actually In my project my head wanted checkbox like above image. So I have used this approach.

Comment: @tymeJV, I had updated it now.

Comment: if you're going to be dynamically changing the element's class(you bind with this) - you should use delegation

Comment: why don't you just use it as background image on the label

Comment: The jsFiddle does not do anything here (I am using Chrome)

Comment: @wirey, can u give example of it? I am not getting what u saying..

Comment: @NickN., I am also using chrome and it is working.

Comment: @NickN., try to click on any checkbox. It will show u the effect.

Comment: the sprite img can't be fetched

Comment: When you bind an event handler to an element - it doesn't matter afterwards if you change the class - it will still have the same event handler bound to it - [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/5w7f6/)  It seems you want to delegate - so you should bind the event handler to a parent element - which will listen for events from elements you specify - Check out the doc here - and depending on which jQuery library you are using use the relevant method [.live/.delegate/.on](http://api.jquery.com/live/#entry-longdesc)

Comment: @ITBeginner heres a better [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/VgkJs/) showing the difference between bind and delegation.  You will notice that binding - it will still trigger the same handler over and over again.  By delegating you are binding to the parent element - so the checks which element the event bubbled up from and handles the even accordingly.  I don't know what browser you're using but if you're using IE or Chrome - hit F12 and go to the console so you can see what's happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind event are saved on page load, so if you want the class `.CheckedCheckBox` to have an action, you must add the binding when you add the class and remove the binding when you remove the class. But this is not a good approach. Using toggleClass is certainly what you need.

Here a fiddle of what i did : http://jsfiddle.net/nscZA/8/

I bind an even on the `checkbox` so you dont have to add/remove it

```
$(".checkBox").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('isChecked');
    if ($(".checkBox").length == $(".isChecked").length) {
       $('.checkBoxAll').addClass('checkAllChecked');
    }else{
        $('.checkBoxAll').removeClass('checkAllChecked');
    }
});
```

It add the class checked and check if all checkbox are checked.

I sugest you explore my solution and ask question if there is something you dont understand.

Note that i changed a little bit your html class / css.

Cheer

Comment: Your jsfiddle is not responding based on the example you have set here on this page.

Comment: Here is the solved one, thanks Karl-André Gagnon, I have updated your answer: Updated link: http://jsfiddle.net/nscZA/8/

Answer (score 4):

IF you want to do it this way, you should be doing this using the `.on` function: reason, you will not have the function (click event management) bound properly for classes it does not currently hold by doing it the way you have.

```
$(document).on('click','.unCheckedCheckBox',function () {...rest of your function
```

NOTE: if possible, put the bind on the closest wrapper, like give the table wrapper and id and do:

```
$('#mytableid').on('click','.unCheckedCheckBox',function () {
```

jQuery 1.9.1 example:  http://jsfiddle.net/nscZA/6/

NOTE Does not use the sprites (not loading) but uses colors

---

EDIT: older delegate with table id:

```
<table id='mytablewrapper'>
```

syntax is slightly different:

```
$('#mytablewrapper').delegate(".CheckedCheckBox", 'click', function () {
```

delegate example: http://jsfiddle.net/nscZA/7/

NOTE Does not use the sprites (not loading) but uses colors

Comment: it seems @ITBeginner is using jQuery 1.6.4 in the fiddle so using `.delegate()` should be the preferred method

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss i said in his/her fiddle up there.. you can't just change the jQuery package in your fiddle to show it works.. You have to work with what he/she gives you - or at least advise that they will have to change their library to use your method

Comment: I was only basing the fildle jQuery version on the one saved last (not by me)...the older one with delegate: http://jsfiddle.net/nscZA/7/

Comment: Thanks @MarkSchultheiss for the classroom lesson today! I did not no that about tables..